# grep result into array

Tags: arrays, shell, grep

I want to count the number of IP's in a given file using this function, the IP's should go into an array so that I can use them later, but I get 'declare: not found' and 'cnt+=1: not found', why is this?

```
#!/bin/bash
searchString=$1
file=$2

countLines()
{
    declare -a ipCount
    cnt=0

    while read line ; do
        ((cnt+=1))

        ipaddr=$( echo "$line" | grep -o -E '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' )

        ((ipCount[$ipaddr]+=1))
    done

    for ip in ${ipCount[*]}
    do
        printf "%-15s %s\n" "$ip" "${ipCount[$ip]}"
    done

    echo "total count=$cnt"
}

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "missing searchString and file"
else
    grep "$searchString" $file | countLines
fi
```

This is a piece of the test file I am trying on

```
Apr 25 11:33:21 Admin CRON[2792]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user 192.168.1.2 by (uid=0)
Apr 25 12:39:01 Admin CRON[2792]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user 192.168.1.2
Apr 27 07:42:07 John CRON[2792]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user 192.168.2.22 by (uid=0)
```

The desired output would be just the IP's inside an array, then also a 'count' on how many IP's there were.

I know I can get the ip's with a grep command but I would like to do more with it later, and it's important that it's in an array.

Comment: What version of bash are you using? What's the output of `/bin/bash --version`? Also, that's a really absurdly complex regex to get IPs. What does your `$line` look like? Why not just (assuming you're on a GNU system) `grep -oP '[0-9.]+'`?

Comment: ,I am using a virtualbox ubuntu :/ it says - GNU bash, version 4.2.25. But the regex is not the problem, what I want to do is have a function that puts the IP's in an array. I'm new to this scripting, so all help is appriciated! ty

Comment: OK, please show the content of `$line` so we can know what the output looks like. You also have various syntax errors but I can't really help unless you show your input and desired output.

Comment: I updated the question with a sample of the testfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two main issues were that you were using `declare -a` but to declare an *associative* array, you need `declare -A`. Then, to iterate over the keys of an associative array, you need to use `for foo in ${!ArrayName[@]}`. I also added some quotes to your variables to be on the safe side:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
searchString="$1"
file="$2"

countLines()
{
    ## You need -A for associative arrays
    declare -A ipCount
    cnt=0

    while read line ; do
        (( cnt+=1 ))

        ipaddr=$( echo "$line" | grep -o -E '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' )
        (( ipCount["$ipaddr"]+=1 ))
    done

    ## To iterate over the keys of an associative
    ## array, you need ${!ArrayName[@]}
    for ip in "${!ipCount[@]}"
    do
        printf "%-15s %s\n" "$ip" "${ipCount[$ip]}"
    done

    echo "total count=$cnt"
}

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "missing searchString and file"
else
    grep "$searchString" "$file" | countLines
fi
```

This is the output of the above on your example file:

```
$ bash a.sh 27 a
192.168.2.22    1
192.168.1.2     2
total count=3
```